# How do i launch new Activity from account icon in contacts

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager, android-syncadapter, android-account

I have an Account Authenticator and Sync Adapter which stored the my app contacts separately into my account. That account icon is also getting displayed for those contacts. But am not getting how to go into an activity once i click the account icon of a particular user.

For eg. If we click the whatsapp icon in our contacts, it leads us to the whatsapp's chat page of that particular user. Like the same way, i need to call an intent that leads to an Activity.

Where should i make the required changes and what code is to be added.

Comment: Have you got the answer??

Comment: have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStreamAcctType

and Do remember to add this intent filter to activity you want to open:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="YOUR MIME TYPE HERE" />
        </intent-filter>
```